# Built-In way to store Pre-Sorted Key-Value Pairs in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable, key-value

I'm looking for a way to maintain the sorting on my key-value pairs. They are sorted by variables outside of the actual key-value pairs (for better UI). I am currently using a **Hashtable**, but that does not maintain the sorting =(

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> subscriptions = getUsersSubscriptions(user);
```

Is there some simple way that Java lets one store pairs? The best idea I can think of is using **2 associated ArrayLists (one of type Integer, another of type String)**. Can someone think of something **better**?

Comment: Use a `Map` implementation as `Hashtable` is considered obsolete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your key-value pairs are already sorted, [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) will maintain order of insertion.

In other words, the keys returned by `map.keySet()` will be in the exact order you put them into the map.

Answer (score 5):

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> myMap = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
```

If you have a custom sorting, pass a [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) instance to the constructor of the [`TreeMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). But be careful doing so, as using a Comparator that does not go well with natural Integer order would make things impossible to understand and debug.

Comment: @Ridudel: Thanks for the edit, but you reverted my TreeSet->TreeMap typo :)

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some simple way that Java lets one store pairs?

Create a custom class that stores the two properties.

> They are sorted by variables outside of the actual key-value pairs

Add a third property for the sort data.

Then your class can implement Comparable to sort the data as required based on this property.

Or you can use a custom Comparator to sort on the sort data field.

Now the class instances can be stored in an ArrayList.